# How to write data to the blockchain using an html form

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, ganache, moralis

I am currently working an Online Birth Certificate Registration System using blockchain for my final year project in Uni. I have incorporated Moralis in my project to handle the users and linked it to Ganache. I am asking if anyone could tell me how to save information from an html form into the blockchain. I have checked online but no one seems to have the exact answers I'm looking for.
Below is the HTML form:
When I click on "add details", I want all the information collected to be saved to the blockchain.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you need to deploy a contract which will store your data on the blockchain. After you deployed the contract you can scrape your html form data with js (or any framework e.g. vue/react) and interact with the contract using e.g. [web3.js](https://medium.com/0xcode/interacting-with-smart-contracts-using-web3-js-34545a8a1ebd).

The contract should look something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract BirthCertificateStorage {

    uint256 dateOfBirth; //save date as unix timestamp or use a string
    string gender;
    string fullName;
    //... with all of your properties

    function storeBirthCertificate(uint256 _dateOfBirth, string calldata _gender, string calldata _fullName) public {
        dateOfBirth = _dateOfBirth;
        gender = _gender;
        fullName = _fullName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement MrFabio_25 answer, you could use Vue.js so the managment of the form data could be a little easier. Then you can use web3, as said before, to interact with your contracts. You'll need connection to a node or to metamask so you can send the transaction.

Your interaction would look something like this:

```
BirthCertificateStorageInstance.methods.storeBirthCertificate(**parameters**)
.send({from: <account>})
.then((response)=>{
    **do something with response**
});
```

I don't know if this is a good practice but I leave here a link to a public project where they use vue, web3 and truffle for the compilation and deployment.

https://github.com/openberry-ac/crowdfunding